# devise missing suburi string in mailer urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app deployed at a suburi: `www.myapp.com/suburi`, and I am having trouble with the urls devise gives me in the reset password mail. It appears that `edit_password_url` does not grab `root_url`, but instead seems to grab the host value from `default_url_options` then appends `new_user_password_path` to it. I have tentatively confirmed this by trying setting `default_url_options = {host: "www.myapp.com/suburi"`}, and I received the correct link in the subsequent email.

This leads me to my question: what is the proper way of setting up devise when deployed on a suburi so that its mailers get the proper `root_url`? Should I be overriding `edit_password_url`, and if so, where would be the best place to do that?